# Explicitly Specifying Lambda Parameter Types

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a little problem with Lambda Expressions. I don't understand this example from C# In a Nutshell book. How can I use fun argument? Can you explain me that or give some other examples? I will be very grateful.

Here's the code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bar((int x) => Foo(x));
    }

    static void Foo<T>(T x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    static void Bar<T>(Action<T> fun)
    {
        fun(5);     // Error: Cannot convert from int to T
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `T` is a cat, how are you going to convert the number `5` to a cat?

Comment: So how can I change the current code to pass value of any type?

Comment: I thought that this line: Bar((int x) => Foo(x)); will set the Foo function to take int arguments. I don't understand this.

Comment: static void Bar(Action<object> fun){  fun(5); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if T is a cat, how are you going to convert the number 5 to a cat? It doesn't make any sense

Something a little easier to get your head around might be

```
static void Main()
{
    Bar(5, x => Foo(x));
    Bar("Bob", x => Foo(x));
}

static void Foo<T>(T x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

static void Bar<T>(T somethingTangible, Action<T> fun)
{
    fun(somethingTangible); 
}
```

**Ouput**

```
5
Bob
```

Comment: Ok, I understand your example, but what is the purpose of the example in this book?

Comment: @BeProo to show you apples cant be converted or cast to cats i guess. I haven't read the book and i don't really know the context though.